# How to avoid data corruption with dual parent/child foreign keys

Tags: database, database-design, sql, sql-server

Imagine the following:

- `Persons` table: `(Id, FirstName, LastName)`
- `PersonEmails` table: `(Id, PersonId, Address)` (to allow a person to have multiple emails)
- `Contacts` table: `(Id, PersonId, UnsubscribeAll)` (special table, because only some people are in the role which allows them to subscribe)
- `Subscribers` table: `(Id, ContactId)` (contact-role people subscribed to something)
- `SubscriberEmails` table: `(Id, SubscriberId, PersonEmailId)` (which email address each person would like to receive the notifications at)

It's trivial to imagine how rows can be inserted into `SubscriberEmails` where `SubscriberId` points at `Subscribers` for one person, but `PersonEmailId` points at `PersonEmails` for another person. Is there way to enforce this logical structure to avoid this corruption?

Possible but clunky solutions:

- Triggers
- Job on a regular schedule to find problems

Comment: Assuming that an API exists whereby changes to the email address lists are maintained, one could simply provide some validation in the API endpoint to prevent the situation you described from occurring.

Comment: @RobertHarvey's suggestion sound reasonable. But, I'm actually curious why you need `SubscriberEmails` at all. Why wouldn't `Subscribers` be `(Id, PersonEmailId)`? You can easily get to `Person` via the `PersonEmail` they subscribed with. (Or to the associated `Contact`.)

Comment: @svidgen I need the `Subscribers` table because 1) it has other state which is by subscriber, and not by email; 2) I have other entities in my model for SMS subscriptions, which share base classes with the email system, and for SMS, a contact can only have one phone number subscribed (per the business requirements).

Comment: Gotcha! I'd favor putting the rules in your API then, as Robert suggested. Restrict write access to the database to that API.

Answer (score 2):

Foreign key relationships don't have to be single columns, you can have "extra" columns in the relations to enforce your requirement.

- `Persons` table with `(Id, ...)`
- `PersonEmails` table with `(Id, PersonId, ...)`, relates to `Persons` by `PersonId`
- `Subscribers` table with `(Id, PersonId, ...)`, relates to `Persons` by `PersonId`
- `SubscriberEmails` table with `(Id, PersonId, SubscriberId, PersonEmailId, ...)`, relates to `Persons` by `PersonsId`, to `PersonEmails` by `(PersonId, PersonEmailId)` and to `Subscribers` by `(PersonId, SubscriberId)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This may work for some others who come across this question. Unfortunately, it won't work for me because 1) I actually have another table, `Contacts`, which `Subscriber` references, and that `Contacts` table has `PersonId`, and `Subscribers.PersonId` actually references `Contacts` table; and 2) it necessitates me adding `PersonId` column to `SubscriberEmails`, which breaks the entity model and is difficult to accomplish cleanly, because I use an ORM. Still, I up-voted your answer because it can be useful to others.

Comment: @Mr.TA: The same advice still applies to your situation, it's just another column to track. However, it looks to me like you're creating a complicated data structure instead of a preliminary data validation procedure, and I'm not convinced that you're taking the path of least resistance here.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check constraint that validates the relationship, the only problem with doing so is that it only validates one end of the relationship.  You either have to add a another check constrain (or validate via a trigger) on the other end.

See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table for some guidance on what you want to do.

Answer (score -2):

The constraints available to most relational databases do not verify things quite to this level. If you ever notice this kind of inconsistency, application code is likely to blame.

You have identified a few solutions to this problem (using triggers or a scheduled job). A (non-exhaustive) list of other alternatives include:

- Stored procedures
- Performing checks in the application layer

You need to choose from a number of possible options. There is no single best solution here, but generally these checks are enforced in triggers, stored procedures, or application code that executes before SQL is sent across the network. The one place it *won't* exist is in the database schema, where I use the term "schema" very loosely to mean "database tables, columns, and constraints."

You will need to make a judgement yourself which layer of the application should handle this. These decisions are subjective by nature, so analyze other code in the application to identify pre-established patterns, or consult your team for further guidance. If you are the one making this judgement call, balance the ease of development, testing, and maintenance with the likelihood that something like this would actually happen.

Comment: SPs are out for me because I use an ORM, and there already exist checks in the application layer, but those failed in this situation (thankfully, it's not a huge problem). I decided to create triggers for now.

I would disagree that this is an application logic problem; under no logical circumstance should the persons be different. It seems to be a schema restriction not being supported by database engines problem to me.

Comment: @Mr.TA: remember what databases were designed for: storing data. Data consistency is a realm that relational databases can help with, but they don't solve all consistency problems. That's why this is an application logic issue.

Comment: I believe this is completely wrong. You could just as well ask how the database could ensure that a foreign key points to an existing row in another table. And yet databases do that all the time as it **is** a data integrity problem and not a business rule problem.

Comment: @user253751: yes, but relational database systems have easily solved that kind of consistency issue using, just as you said, foreign key constraints. The kind of inconsistency the OP is talking about is **not** a constraint that relational databases have solved. I never said this wasn't a data integrity problem. I was saying that an RDMS does not have a solution using constraints, and instead you need to choose from a number of other options, some of which reside outside of the database.

Comment: @GregBurghardt then you're going to have to justify why a "single foreign key" is something databases should solve and a "double foreign key" is something they shouldn't. Keep in mind that you did not answer that no database currently has this feature - you answered that this is a bad feature that no database should ever have.

Comment: @user253751: I'm not arguing where the solution should exist. Again, I'm just saying that you cannot use database constraints, you need to choose from a number of possible solutions, and there is no general, widely accepted answer. I think you are misunderstanding my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify the second to last paragraph. Perhaps that was the cause of confusion.

Comment: you literally said this is a business operations problem and not a database problem

Comment: @user253751, I revised the first paragraph. It seems that people have focused on the first paragraph, rather than "there is no general solution to this problem."

Comment: "If you ever notice this kind of inconsistency, application code is likely to blame." is still obvious, still useless and still saying the application code needs to enforce data integrity, which I remind you, is antithetical to the point of relational databases.